# Why is an interchange of the summation and the integral here not justified?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, analysis, power-series

I'm trying to solve the following integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x\;\text{.}
\end{equation}
After some time I found out that
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{1}{4}\Gamma'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{equation}
Then I tried to evaluate $\Gamma'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ which lead me to
\begin{equation}
\Gamma'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\sqrt{\pi}\left(2+\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+2n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{equation}
After that I tried to evaluate the sum with some integrals. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+2n}-\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(2\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x\right)
\end{equation}
After some change of index I finally came to
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(2\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+2}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\mathrm{d}x\right)
=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Now my problem:

In the last line is a mistake and I don't know why.
Before I used the geometric series the integral numerically goes to $-2+\ln(4)$, but after the use it goes to $-2+\ln(2)$. Why is here an interchange of limits not justified?

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(2\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+2}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\mathrm{d}x\right)=-2+\ln(4) \\
2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x}\mathrm{d}x=-2+\ln(2)
\end{align}

[image: Evaluation]

Comment: The integrals don't even converge, so surely they cannot evaluate to $-2+\ln(2)$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But if I maipulate the second integral the diverging parts cancel each other. And the first one you just need to look on Wolfram Alpha or am I wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by cancelling the diverging parts.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You can use the fact that $x^2=-(1-x^2)+1$ and the PFD

Comment: So? You still have two separate integrals, both of which diverge.

Comment: I've edited the post. Can you see what I mean?

Comment: It is certainly not the case that you can simply cancel integrals that diverge like that.

Comment: If I write the limits and the use the $\lim a+\lim b=\lim (a+b)$ I think it justified?

Comment: Only if two of those limits exists.

Comment: So I can't do any manipulation because the limits do not exist? Thank You

Comment: Seeing as the last two integrals are polynomials, you might as well just integrate them as normal. However it is still a good question. The answer is because the integrals of these functions don't converge individually, but the integral of the difference does converge.

Comment: $2n+1$ not $2n+2$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as computing $\Gamma'(1/2)$ goes, note that it equals $\Gamma(1/2)\psi(1/2)$, where $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$ is well-known and $\psi$ is the digamma function given by

\begin{align}\psi(1/2)&=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n-1/2}\right)\\&=-\gamma+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n-1}\right)\\&=-\gamma-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n\\&=-\gamma-2\ln(2)\\&=-\gamma-\ln(4)\end{align}

which is the proper result. Hence $\Gamma'(1/2)=-\sqrt\pi(\gamma+\ln(4))$.

---

As for what you've done, it is not valid to split a sum into two diverging sums, and hence this falls apart at

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac2{1+2n}-\frac1n\right)\stackrel!=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{1+2n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$

which is simply false. This can be amended by simply not splitting the sum apart.

Comment: Or taking the sum to m instead of $\infty$ and seeing what happens as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, if ever in doubt of a series manipulation, check the behavior of the partial sums.